# How to I set a variable based on another value in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to iterate through a hash of key/value pairs and set a variable based on one of the keys being a certain value.

```
    @custom_fields = [{
      "field_id" => "6",
      "field_identifier" => "NROM_Password",
      "field_type" => "input_field",
      "field_value" => "NROM Password 1"
    }, {
      "field_id" => "5",
      "field_identifier" => "NROM_Username",
      "field_type" => "input_field",
      "field_value" => "NROM Username 1"
    }]
```

I want to set a variable called `@username` to the `field_value` key's value, only if the `field_identifier` key is equal to "NROM_Username" AND if the `field_value` is not empty.

Here is the code snippet that I have so far:

```
@custom_fields.each do |custom_field|
  custom_field.each do |field_key, field_value|
    if (field_key == "field_identifier" && field_value == "NROM_Username")
      @password = (field_key == "NROM_Password" && value?) ? value : ""
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: i don't get your logic, you check `field_key == "field_identifier"` then inside `if` you check `field_key == "NROM_Password"`

Comment: It's better to check directly `custom_field['field_identifier'] == 'NROM_Username' ... `, no need to loop through every pair {key, value} each custom_field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the sub-hash containing `"NROM_Username"` as its `"field_identifier"` via [`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerable.html#find-method): (assuming there's exactly one)

```
hash = @custom_fields.find { |h| h['field_identifier'] == 'NROM_Username' }
#=> {"field_id"=>"5", "field_identifier"=>"NROM_Username", ... }
```

The `@username` variable can then be set by fetching the hash's value for `"field_value"`, e.g.:

```
@username = hash['field_value']
#=> "NROM Username 1"
```

To restrict this assignment to non-emtpy values, you can add a conditional, e.g.: (depending on what "empty" means):

```
# assigns if the key exists
@username = hash['field_value'] if hash.has_key?('field_value')

# assigns if the key is "truthy", i.e. neither nil nor false
@username = hash['field_value'] if hash['field_value']

# assigns if the key isn't "blank", e.g. empty string or whitespace only
@username = hash['field_value'] unless hash['field_value'].blank?
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, breakdown and the great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = @custom_fields.inject({}) do |memo, cf|
  memo.merge(cf["field_identifier"] => cf["field_value"].presence)
end.compact

# this is kind of silly - nil is nil
@username = hash["NROM_Username"] if hash["NROM_Username"]
```

Comment: _"nil is nil"_ – maybe `@username` isn't `nil`.